# How can I use youtube_dl with a discord.py bot?

Tags: discord.py

I am making a music discord bot using python and I am having an issue where I download the video as a .webm file but then ffmpeg is not able to read this file and throws the error below.

```
ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
2022-11-30 20:57:06 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2115, in post_process
    files_to_delete, info = pp.run(info)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\postprocessor\ffmpeg.py", line 277, in run
    raise PostProcessingError('WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe')
youtube_dl.utils.PostProcessingError: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\code.py", line 31, in play
    ydl.download([url])
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2068, in download
    res = self.extract_info(
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 815, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 847, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 881, in process_ie_result
    return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1692, in process_video_result
    self.process_info(new_info)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2050, in process_info
    self.post_process(filename, info_dict)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2117, in post_process
    self.report_error(e.msg)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\willf\Desktop\DiscordBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
```

Here is my current code. It breaks between line 30 and 35.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="q!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    # song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    # try:
    #     if song_there:
    #         os.remove("song.mp3")
    # except PermissionError:
    #     await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
    #     return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()

client.run('Token')
```

I have tried converting the file to an mp3 but I am unsure how to get this to work properly. All I need is for the .webm file to be converted to a .mp3 file so that discord can read this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ffmpeg to path

- Open windows search bar and open up 'edit the system environment variables'
- Then click on environment variables on the bottom
- Click on path and edit
- after that just find where you downloaded ffmpeg and add it

Comment: I have already done that but it can not covert it for some reason.

Comment: even if there was a way to stream the audio directly that would be better because downloads take for ever.